# Populate Week Start and Week End dates given the Year and Week Number in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a combo box on access form from which a user can select a particular year, say 2014 from a drop-down. Another combo box exists on this form which has a drop-down of the week numbers from 1 to 53. These two combo boxes are not linked. (Or do I have to link/bound them?)
Also, there are two text boxes named, *"WeekStart"* and *"WeekEnd"* on this form. 
 
What I want to do is to have the week start and end dates for the selected week number and year to be populated in the *"WeekStart"* and *"WeekEnd"* textboxes. I'm starting my week on a Sunday. I put this code in the *"After Update"* event of the *"week number"* combo box.

> `Me.WeekStart = DateSerial(Me.cboYear, 1, Me.cboWeekNum * 7)`

But I know this is not right, and I'm stucked. Any help would be appreciated. And also, is it essential that I bound the week number to the year? If so, how do I go about that too. Thank you

Comment: Problem is, that you will have overlapping week numbers around New Year. Can't you use the _ISO 8601_ week numbers which work around this?

Comment: @Gustav, I just googled ISO 8601 week numbers to find out what actually it is. Is there any way you could direct me in the right direction with regards to how and what I need to do? Thank you

Comment: You don't need to relate weeks combo to year combo. So what do you want for week 1 of 2016? (1) The partial week that starts on Friday, Jan 1, or the full week that starts on Sunday Jan 3? Using ISO standard, Jan 1, 2016 is week 53.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn: Alright. To my understanding, the first week of 2016 starts on January 3, 2016

Comment: The crucial point is that ISO 8601 weeks begin Monday. Can you accept that?

Comment: @Gustav: From researching, I realized that ISO 8601 weeks begin on Monday, and my task requires me to start my week on a Sunday. Is there any work-around with this? Thank you all for your patience and sharing.

Comment: No, then you have to define your own method.

Comment: @Gustav: Alright, thank you. Then I guess I might have to adjust to the ISO 8061 week number. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a VBA function to calculate the week's start date. For example, with a form like this:

[image: frmWeekStart.png]

you can use form code like this

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cboWeekNum_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateStartEndDates
End Sub

Private Sub cboYear_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateStartEndDates
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateStartEndDates()
    Me.txtWeekStart.Value = WeekStartDate(Me.cboYear.Value, Me.cboWeekNum.Value)
    Me.txtWeekEnd.Value = DateAdd("d", 6, Me.txtWeekStart.Value)
End Sub

Private Function WeekStartDate(yyyy As Integer, ww As Integer) As Date
    ' per ISO 8601, week starts on Monday
    Dim Jan1 As Date
    Jan1 = DateSerial(yyyy, 1, 1)
    Dim Jan1Weekday As Integer
    Jan1Weekday = Weekday(Jan1, vbThursday)
    Dim FirstThursday As Date
    ' per standard, Week 1 contains the first Thursday of the year
    FirstThursday = DateAdd("d", IIf(Jan1Weekday = 1, 0, 8 - Jan1Weekday), Jan1)
    ' back up 3 days to Monday, then add 7 days for each week after Week 1
    WeekStartDate = DateAdd("d", -3 + (7 * (ww - 1)), FirstThursday)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm trying to fully understand the VBA function you have provided. It's my first time using the "Public Function" . Could you please explain to me the last two lines, thus "FirstThursday" and "WeekStartDate"? Thus, the logic behind the equation? And also, does this code go into my After-update event of my *"Week number"* combo box? Or simply put, how do I use the function? I'm sorry, I'm just new to this.. :-( Thanks once again

Comment: Thank you for your response. @Gord Thompson.. Even though I really wanted my week to start on a Sunday, I think I can be flexible on letting it start on a Monday (per ISO 8601). Thank you for your time and great clarification. I appreciate you and everyone else on here helping to share their great knowledge and expertise.